# outer variables define inside a class

Tags: php, oop

how do you define a variable in a class? seems like global only works inside the function.

```
<?php

$a = '20';
$b = '10';

class test {
global $a; $b;


    function add() {


        echo $a;

    }


}

$answer = new test();

$answer->add();

?php>
```

i tried this one (use global inside a class but gets error instead)
also, how can you define multiple variables in just 1 line of code instead of defining it each.

Comment: There is an example in the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php - Reading/Browsing the manual is a must..

Comment: I edited the post and didn't fix this probable typo `?php>` and didn't know if that is you used or not. Please edit accordingly. I don't want to see anyone else fix it in an edit if it's actually the code you used in your working file. In any case, fixing code isn't part of editing other than by the OP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about passing the data in via the constructor?

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1befY))

```
$a_outside = '20';
$b_outside = '10';

class test {
    public $a_inside;
    public $b_inside;

    public function __construct($a_passed_in, $b_passed_in)
    {
        $this->a_inside = $a_passed_in;
        $this->b_inside = $b_passed_in;
    }

    public function add()
    {
        echo $this->a_inside + $this->b_inside;
    }
}

$answer = new test($a_outside, $b_outside);
$answer->add();  // output: 30
```

1. Pass the variable to the class via arguments in the constructor call.
2. Define the values as variables in the class within construct call.
3. Access the variables within the `add()` method.

Answer (score 0):

To define a class property (or variable), you would do like so:

```
class Foo {

  private $myVar = 'my var'; // define a class property

  public function add() {
    echo $this->myVar; 
  }

}
```